# How to adapt tf.contrib.data.TextLineDataset for text from other sources?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, if my text data come from a database, how can I get one line/doc(as a database record) using the same mechanism (subclassing `Dataset` such that the pipeline described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_text_data) still works) as `TextLineDataset` ?

By looking at the source code of `TextLineDataset`, I find that `make_dataset_resource()` seems an import method to be implemented. But I can't find where the actual code of yielding a line from a file as the docstring of `TextLineDataset` says: `A Dataset comprising lines from one or more text files.`

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I read somewhere in the github commits for the next TF version that they are implementing a Dataset class to read from databases, you might want to look into that (might give you a starting point). I'll see if I can find a link to it

Comment: Check out the [SqlDataset class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3bc73f5e2ac437b1d9d559751af789c8c965a7f9/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py#L2275) which is not yet released (so be careful, it might still be buggy!)

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks for mentioning this. It seems that having custom class is not that easy to implemented since it requires one write the ops in c++.

Comment: While it may not be quite as performant (and adds a dependence on the Python interpreter for graph execution), you can [use py_func with the Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#applying_arbitrary_python_logic_with_tfpy_func) to read data using Python code.